# Q: How does LUIS understand names or proper nouns?

Tags: android-intent, contacts, entities, azure-language-understanding

My question is: Does LUIS know what a Proper Noun is? And if so, what makes a proper noun for LUIS? And therefore, how can I get it to reliably recognise a name for, say, a $ContactName across intents in different contexts? For example, would it help to train it with Utterances, or with a PhraseList?

I'm working with LUIS to create lines that pickup proper names as Contacts in the right context. I'm having a hard time getting it to work consistently.

I have attempted working with both utterances and phrase lists. The phrase lists do not appear to work well, while utterances seeming to work rather well.

My process has been to create a Book.Meeting intent, a [$Contact] entity, and start with three utterances:

```
meeting with [john] 
meeting with [john smith]
meeting with [john van smith]
```

I then trained the app and tested some inputs:

```
input:                        output:
Meeting with john             meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with john smith       meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with smith john       meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with john van smith   meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with smith van john   meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with john smith van   meeting with [$Contact] van 
Meeting with smith john van   meeting with [$Contact]
```

So I found that order didn't seem to matter most of the time, unless the word van, seemingly unknown to its wordhoard, fell outside the known proper nouns. So I wanted to see what it would count as a [Contact] under those conditions. I ran some more tests to see what the outputs would be with other words, including proper nouns, adjectives and adverbs:

```
input:                        output:
Meeting with blue              meeting with [$Contact]  
Meeting with blue smith        meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with blue van smith    meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with blue della smith  meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with blue della table  meeting with [$Contact] table 
Meeting with table della blue  meeting with [$Contact] blue 
Meeting with blue van table    meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with table van blue    meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with hungry            meeting with [$Contact]  
Meeting with sad               meeting with [$Contact]  
Meeting with shut              meeting with [$Contact]  
Meeting with shut door         meeting with [$Contact] 
Meeting with shut door now     meeting with [$Contact] now 
Meeting with shut open door    meeting with [$Contact] door
```

So I found that within the right context, LUIS will pickup any words that are in its wordhoard, so substituting "john" for "smith", or a noun "table", an adjective "blue" or even an adverb such as "shut", LUIS will pick it up as a Contact entity. However, it seemed to like two-word names best. Additionally, some words didn't work as well as others, so it seems to like proper nouns better than what it reads as nouns (say, "john" more than "van"). It also seems that if a word is not in its wordhoard, such as "blazoops", it doesn't know how to deal with it. The problem with that is that many Proper Nouns will not be in its dictionary. So I sought to train it to recognise what it sees as gibberish as equal to the proper nouns that it knows, so long as it's in the right context. I threw out the test app and started anew. I did a series of utterances, mixing the order of proper nouns with gibberish in growing order of words to include a person's full name.

```
Book a meeting with [john] 
Book a meeting with [john smith] 
Book a meeting with [john aishsds] 
Book a meeting with [jskjhd smith] 
Book a meeting with [john skjsdkj smith] 
Book a meeting with [kjsdjkhsd john smith] 
Book a meeting with [ljksjd skjsdk smith] 
Book a meeting with [john smith] and [jane doe] 
Book a meeting with [john sikhsd] and [jane skdjsd] 
Book a meeting with [sdsd smith] and [sdsd doe]
```

I then found it was pretty consistently picking up any names I threw at it so long as it was within that context. Without including any in my utterances, it also included names with apostrophes (O'Brien) and hyphens (Smith-Jones). However, trying different variations of that command with only those utterances caused problems. For example, when I input:

```
I'd like to book a meeting with kjhasiuhd sihdh and iojoia shhds
```

it gave me the output:

```
[I'd like to] book a meeting with [kjhasiuhd sihdh] and [iojoia shhds]
```

So it was picking up the "I'd like to" at the start as a Contact/name. I was able to fix this by adding that utterance and telling LUIS that the starting words were not in fact a $Contact. That one utterance seemed to be enough to fix that hiccup.

Another thing I noticed was that it understood the keyword "and" separated two names, but did not always understand where the full two-word or more name started and ended if it was not a known proper noun next to the keyword. For example the full two-word names found in "meeting with sdsd smith and jane soidjsd" were more likely to be understood than "meeting with john ssds and asdsd smith".

But now for the most part it was treating any string of words at the end of an utterance as a name. So the next step was to setup more intents. I setup a $datetime intent, and a $Location intent. I then gave it some more utterances:

```
Book a meeting with [hsdsd kjsjs] and [sjhsd aoowj] for [12pm] 
Book a meeting with [kjhskjhd sjasd] and [jaskdhsd sjdhkshd] for [12pm] at [the eatery]
```

With those utterances in total I could get it to recognise just about anything as a $Contact name within the right context, separated with the right keywords. It also worked with patterns of known synonyms, so for example, the following also worked well:

```
organise an appointment with [hsdsd kjsjs] and [sjhsd aoowj] for [9am]
```

I imported those utterances into a copy of a larger app that I was working on which has much more intents and entities, to see how LUIS would parse it with the greater complexity. I was glad to see that programming those utterances into the Book.Meeting intent in the main app not only worked just as well as it did in the mini test app, it also carried over into other intents, so "book meeting with [blah zippity]..." would work as well as "lookup [blah zippity]" with both the intent and entities being correctly recognised.

I was hoping to make this all a lot simpler by avoiding needing the scores of utterances and instead only making up a PhraseList. I took the same overall logic, and created PhraseLists such as:

> john,jane,john smith,jane smith,john o ' brien,jane o ' brien,robert,thomas,wilson,williams,howard,ethel,jones,akaash,Liu,cheng,mildred,florence,tuscany,lancaster,wei,marion,walters,helen,chester,richland,jia,johnston,harrison,greenwood,julie,dennis,connie,sharon,douglas,craig,greg,lisa,brian,sarah,peter,karen,van schmidt,james,scott,jackson,davis,david,michael,keith,andrew,lee,franklin,kjhskdhk sdfkjhdsfhm,kjksdfkhj john,john jhskjdsd,john askjdhs sksdsd,askdjhsdk john skjhdk,shkhoihwd asdjkhsd smith

I was hoping this would work even better since it would give a greater wealth of example for LUIS to work with. However, giving it that PhraseList and the example utterances as in the beginning failed to yield any consistent results. So as far as I can tell, it's not treating the 'synonyms' in the PhraseList right when it comes to identifying entities.

In conclusion, using the aforesaid Utterances methods makes the name recognition work pretty well but still not 100%. Has anyone had a similar problem and found a good, consistent fix for LUIS recognising names?  Regardless, I hope this helps anyone going through a similar problem.

Comment: Back-end of LUIS is most probably something like this: [MS Linguistic API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/linguistic-analysis-api/). LUIS will work exactly like you described and I think there is no way to handle this in LUIS itself. Of course, you cannot specify all of the examples for Proper Nouns, so `phrase lists` and `list entities` won't work. If your examples have structure, maybe you can use `pattern features`.

Comment: Maybe you can try other MS service like [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/entity-linking-intelligence-service/) to find the proper nouns, and use LUIS only for recognizing intents

Answer (score 0):

Use Patterns with applicable intents and keywords as part of patterns

example pattern:

Book a meeting with [name]... as long as 'book a meeting with' wordings are same the entity [name] can take up any name

Add conversationally complementing variations of patterns for the intent.